# Is there a way to change the system font completely?

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to change the system font completely? I mean I want the font from login in screen until every application follow the change.

Answer (score 1):

The font settings are stored in gconf and can be changed easily with `gnome-appearance-properties`. They can also be changed using `gconf-editor` or the commandline-tool `gconftool-2`.

If you want to change the fonts of the login-screen you have to run these tools as the user *gdm* like this:

```
sudo -u gdm dbus-launch gnome-appearance-properties
```

In some cases this doesn't work and you have to go a more complicated way:

1. Log out (so that you are on the login screen)
2. figure out what displaynumber the login screen has by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>(<kbd>F8</kbd>,<kbd>F9</kbd>). If the login screen is on <kbd>F7</kbd> its number is 0, on <kbd>F8</kbd> it is 1, ..
3. change to a blank terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in with your user. Now run the above command like this (with the correct DISPLAY):

   `sudo -u gdm DISPLAY=:0 dbus-launch gnome-appearance-properties`
4. now change back to GDM and you should see the appearance properties dialog where you can make any changes you like (background, too).

Comment: Any idea how this has changed with the move to LightDM (from gdm)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to go to System-->Preferences-->Appearance-->Fonts and change it from there.

Comment: the font at login screen won't follow the change.